# How to append virtual record in query result set

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a query that returns a result set that has a date column as shown at the image attached
what I needed to do is append a fek record for the missing date (the yellow rows in the image)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to UNION data you're missing.

This is your current query:

```
select id, type, event_date, previous_date
from ...
where ...
-- now, add missing rows:
union all
select null, null, date '2023-09-28', null from dual union all
select null, null, date '2023-09-30', null from dual union all
... add as many rows as you need
```

---

If that has to be *smarter* than that, find missing dates:

```
insert into target_table (id, type, event_date, previous_date)
with 
temp as
  (select min(trunc(event_date)) start_date,
          max(trunc(event_date)) end_date
   from target_table
  ),
calendar as
  (select start_date + level - 1 as event_date
   from temp
   connect by level <= end_date - start_date + 1
  ),
missing_dates as
  (select event_date from calendar
   minus
   select trunc(event_date) from target_table
  )
select null, null, event_date, null
from missing_dates
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a row-generator to generate a calendar and then use an `OUTER JOIN` to combine it with your current table:

```sql
WITH calendar (dt, max_dt) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(MIN(event_date)),
         TRUNC(MAX(event_date))
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + 1,
         max_dt
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  dt + 1 <= max_dt
),
prev_dates (id, type, event_date, prev_event_date) AS (
  SELECT id,
         type,
         event_date,
         LAG(event_date)
           OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_date)
           AS prev_event_date
  FROM   table_name
)
SELECT p.id,
       p.type,
       COALESCE(p.event_date, c.dt) AS event_date,
       p.prev_event_date
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN prev_dates p
       PARTITION BY (p.id)
       ON (c.dt <= p.event_date AND p.event_date < c.dt + 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, type, event_date) AS
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-05' + INTERVAL '01:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-05' + INTERVAL '02:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-07' + INTERVAL '01:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-07' + INTERVAL '02:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-08' + INTERVAL '03:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14020200, 'Ttype', DATE '1970-01-09' + INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TYPE | EVENT_DATE | PREV_EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-01 12:34:56 | *null* |
| 14020200 | *null* | 1970-01-02 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 14020200 | *null* | 1970-01-03 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 14020200 | *null* | 1970-01-04 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-05 01:00:00 | 1970-01-01 12:34:56 |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-05 02:00:00 | 1970-01-05 01:00:00 |
| 14020200 | *null* | 1970-01-06 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-07 01:00:00 | 1970-01-05 02:00:00 |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-07 02:00:00 | 1970-01-07 01:00:00 |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-08 03:00:00 | 1970-01-07 02:00:00 |
| 14020200 | Ttype | 1970-01-09 12:34:56 | 1970-01-08 03:00:00 |

*Note: The above query will work for multiple `id` values and generate the missing calendar entries for each because of the `PARTITION BY` clause in the join. If you do not want this then just remove the `PARTITION BY` clause and you will only get one row for each missing date (not one row per id per missing date) and the `id` column for those rows will be `NULL`. Several examples demonstrating the difference are in the fiddle below.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QbzwltlZ)